# automatically click an element on a webpage with tampermonkey?

Tags: javascript, html, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

I am trying to get the last page of results from *Factiva*. I hope to automically click the button `Next 100`.

An image to provide more information: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pc3D4.png)

I already tried the script `AutoClicker`. It works for `modify search` button but fails to click `Next 100`.

Error shown as:

> Autoclicker does not find the click object!

I was wondering whether the *Xpath* I used is wrong.

**the element**:

```
    <a class="nextItem" href="javascript:void(0)"
      onclick="viewNext('241');return false">Next 100 </a>
```

**the selector**:

```
    #headlineHeader33 > table > tbody > tr > td > a.nextItem
```

**the Xpath**:

```
    //*[@id="headlineHeader33"]/table/tbody/tr/td/a[2]
```

Here is the code I used:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

var cyce = 1000;

var str_xpath = '//*[@id="headlineHeader33"]/table/tbody/tr/td/a[2]';
// another way,e.g: var str_qs = "div .search span a";
var str_qs = "";



function getTargetById(t_id){
    var target = document.getElementById(t_id);
    return target;
}


function getTargetByTAV(t_tag,t_attr,t_value){
    var target = document.getElementsByTagName(t_tag);
    for(var i=0;i <target.length;i++){
        if(target[i].getAttribute(t_attr) == t_value){
            return target[i];
        }
    }
}

function getTargetByXpath(str_xpath) {
    var xresult = document.evaluate(str_xpath, document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
    var xnodes = [];
    var xres;
    while (xres = xresult.iterateNext()) {
        xnodes.push(xres);
    }
    return xnodes;
}


function getTargetByQS(str_qs){
    var target = document.querySelector(str_qs);
    return target;
}


function trim(str){
    str = str.replace(/(^\s*)|(\s*$)/g, "");
    return str;
}


var btn;

if(isCustiom === true){
    btn = getTargetByCustom();
}

if(trim(id) !== "" && (btn === null | typeof(btn) !== 'object')){
    btn = getTargetById(id);
}

if(trim(tag) !== "" && trim(attr) !== "" && value !== "" && (btn === null | typeof(btn) !== 'object')){
    btn = getTargetByTAV(tag,attr,value);
}

if(trim(str_xpath) !== "" && (btn === null | typeof(btn) !== 'object')){
    btn = getTargetByXpath(str_xpath)[0];
}

if(trim(str_qs) !== "" && (btn === null | typeof(btn) !== 'object')){
    btn = getTargetByQS(str_qs);
}

setInterval(function() {
        if (btn !== null && typeof(btn) === 'object') {
            console.info("[+] AutoClicker click object: " + btn.innerHTML);
            btn.click();
        }else{
            console.warn('[-] Autoclicker does not find the click object!');
        }
    },cyce);
})();
```

Comment: The code that you've posted contains the xpath-query above the declaration, probably this is commented out in your own code. If the above code is used verbatim, then it will error out on that line.

Comment: The problem is probably your `xPath-query`. It is not able to find a valid `btn`-object and cycles back a warning every second.

Comment: Oh sorry. That error is not in my real code.

Answer (score 0):

I can't help you with the xPath because I don't know how the document is formed. However your script also provides a way to select the element with [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector). Which selects elements using [*css-selectors*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors). **I highly recommend going with this more modern solution**.

```
function getTargetByQS(str_qs){
    var target = document.querySelector(str_qs);
    return target;
}
```

The only thing you need to do is provide the `str_qs` and the correct selector:

**selector**

```
a.nextItem[onclick*='viewNext']
```

The selector looks for an anchor element `a` with classname `nextItem` and the property `onclick` containing `viewNext`.

**The string**

```
str_qs = "a.nextItem[onclick*='viewNext']";
```

See the solution in action:

```js
var timer;
(function() {
    'use strict';

//stripped all other functions just to demonstrate the function getTargetByQS

var cyce = 1000;

var str_qs = "a.nextItem[onclick*='viewNext']";

function getTargetByQS(str_qs){
    var target = document.querySelector(str_qs);
    return target;
}


function trim(str){
    str = str.replace(/(^\s*)|(\s*$)/g, "");
    return str;
}


var btn;
if(trim(str_qs) !== "" && (btn === null | typeof(btn) !== 'object')){
    btn = getTargetByQS(str_qs);
}

timer = setInterval(function() {
        if (btn !== null && typeof(btn) === 'object') {
            console.info("[+] AutoClicker click object: " + btn.innerHTML);
            btn.click();
        }else{
            console.warn('[-] Autoclicker does not find the click object!');
        }
    },cyce);
})();

//not part of the solution, just for the demo.
function viewNext(){
  window.clearInterval(timer); //shut down the interval for demo-purposes
}
```

```html
  <a class="nextItem" href="javascript:void(0)"
      onclick="viewNext('241');return false">Next 100 </a>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution! But unfortunately it still shows  "Autoclicker does not find the click object! " And one thing to mention, the button "Previous 100 " also includes "viewNext"   -----<a class="previousItem" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="viewNext('0');return false">Previous 100 </a>